# Windows Batch: use full path of file in FOR /F

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm doing a batch file to robocopy certain folders, and I'm using a text file to pass the batch which folders should be copy. So:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (resources.txt) do (
    robocopy \\server-old\%%A\ f:\Resources\%%A\ /s /e /copyall /secfix /zb /r:3 /w:5 /mt:32 /log+:c:\robocopy_%%A.)
```

All works fine, except when I try to replace `resources.txt` (relative path) for `c:\somefolder\resources.txt` (absolute path, no spaces, no strange characters), then I get:

```
    ) was unexpected at this time.
```

I tried double quotes (same result), doubling the backslashes (so, `c:\\somefolder\\resources.txt`) and single quotes (which strangely opened up the file with my editor! O.o).

I've a workaround for this, but still want to know what I'm doing wrong here... Ah! It's on a WinServer 2008R2 Enterprise. Thanks!

Comment: It works either way for me (relative or fully specified path). Is there more code around this that you didn't show here?

Comment: Actually yes: it was a comment going further than I wanted it to... Thanks for forgetting this dumb question  :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake: as @aphoria comments, works either way: a comment was causing the issue. Or to be more clear, myself and few hours of sleep were causing this not-issue.